# Need to get value from database without refresh

Tags: javascript, php, ajaxform

I'm creating an system that seperates your invoice in parts. You set these up in the administration panel i build. Example:

If the price is between 200 and 1000 and the minimal invoice price is 250 then give 4 terms. NOW when customers fill in the registration forms i want it to show up without page refresh. Like:

Input invoice price:

$500

---

You can pay this invoice in 4 terms

This has to be dynamicly.

I've setted up the database table with all the values.

Short story:

I want to take out how many terms the customer got when filling in an random invoice price. The system must check through the database if theres a number in it which matches the input field. Then get from the database how many terms it has.

Database table:

```
id     min_price     max_price     minimal_invoice_price     terms
1      200           1000          250                       4
```

Comment: Why can't this value be loaded on initial page request?

Comment: How can i achieve this? i'm a total disaster with javascript :/

Comment: Have you tried an Ajax request

Comment: I know it can be achieved with ajax request but i don't realy know how i check if the inputted value is between a value from the database then check the terms from it. I only know this using php but then i need to submit the form :/

Answer (score -1):

If you are lacking the method to do this, I would suggest reviewing the below article which will present you an AJAX way to do it dynamically, without refreshing the page.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_database.asp

If you have problems with the code you can post your attempt here for further help.

Comment: Thank your comment, i will take a look and try to understand js.

Comment: I have php code that gets all the values stored in that table from the database. Now i need javascript to check the input field if its between an number then give the term in return but i don't know how to achieve this because i can't develop in javascript. I can only develop in php but my project currently needs javascript god damned i need to learn it lol